# Flutter web - go_router - read value after hash #

Tags: flutter, uri, hashtag, flutter-go-router, gorouter

Given the url: `/path#someValue` I would like to get the value after #, which is exactly the `someValue`.

```
GoRoute(path: 'path', pageBuilder: (context, state) {
   // I need to get: `someValue` here
}),
```

I am using GoRouter and `setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());`

It doesn't seem that `someValue` is present anywhere in the `state`.

`state.fullPath` contains: `/path`.

It seems like the hash value gets stripped immediately.

Is there any way to get the proper value after `#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it is on the web so it is so you can use:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

GoRoute(path: 'path', pageBuilder: (context, state) {
  String valorHash = html.window.location.hash;
  valorHash = valorHash.startsWith('#') ? valorHash.substring(1) : valorHash;

}),
```

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately the: `html.window.location.hash` is empty string on my side. By the time the `pageBuilder` runs and the: `html.window.location.hash` line is reached the hash is already stripped from the browser path.

Comment: It seems that hash is lost in the `url_strategy.dart:getPath()` and then subsequent call to: `replaceState` removes it completely from the browser.
If I modify the `getPath()` so the hash is preserved, then such path is no longer pattern matched to `GoRouter` routes. Probably have to reach out to: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: In fact the issue was on my side due to: `redirect` configured for `go_router` which was exact matching routes based on `state.location`. When hash was added the redirect no longer worked as it should. Thanks for your help.